# puppet variable parsing inside quotes

Tags: puppet, parsing

How can I make the last exec resource parse variables?

Currently it is coming out blank inside rc.local file as such:

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/balance -b 127.0.0.1 3306 :3306 ! :3306
```

Also for clarification, the "run-balance" exec resource produces the correct output with properly parsed variables and these are the same variables used in the following "add-rclocal" resource.

Class

```
class balance ( 
$dbserver1 = 'server1', 
$dbserver2 = 'server2',
) {

package { 'balance': ensure => "installed",

}->

exec { 'run-balance': 
 command => "/usr/sbin/balance -b 127.0.0.1 3306 ${dbserver1}:3306 ! ${dbserver2}:3306", 
 unless => '/bin/ps afx | grep balance > /dev/null',

}->

exec { 'add-rclocal': 
  command => "echo '/usr/sbin/balance -b 127.0.0.1 3306 ${dbserver1}:3306 ! ${dbserver2}:3306' >> /etc/rc.local",

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can come up with that would produce your results is if `dbserver2` is being passed in as an empty string. It will be defined, but empty, so it won't assign the default. Sort of like:

```
class { 'balance':
  dbserver1 => 'dbhost1',
  dbserver2 => '',
}
```

You'll probably want to check your inputs. And maybe put something like this in to interrogate what those variables are being assigned as:

```
warning("Balance was passed servers ${dbserver1} and ${dbserver2}.")
```

Which will emit the variables in the log-stream.